# Problem with installation of Gin via 'go get github.com/gin-gonic/gin'

Tags: go, go-gin

I am trying to install `Gin` but facing the following issues in the Ubuntu terminal:

```
/go/src$ go get github.com/gin-gonic/gin
package github.com/gin-gonic/gin: no Go files in /home/user/go/src/github.com/gin-gonic/gin
```

When I use `-u` the error is a bit another:

```
/go/src$ go get -u github.com/gin-gonic/gin
package github.com/gin-gonic/gin: directory "/home/user/go/src/github.com/gin-gonic/gin" is not using a known version control system
```

I tried a hard installation:

```
sudo apt-get install -y golang-github-gin-gonic-gin-dev
```

but there is a lot of inconvenience like `lib/pq` disappears when saving- mean mod.go doesn't permit installation and when running main.go in Gin project -> facing the following issue:

```
Lec13$ go run main.go
routes/routes.go:4:2: package Lec13/controllers is not in GOROOT (/usr/local/go/src/Lec13/controllers)
```

Maybe someone knows the way to figure this issue out?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: CAn you post your folder/file structure? Do you have a module `go.mod`, `go.sum` in your root path?

Comment: Hi  @Danizavtz , sure: /go/src/github.com/RaminCH_self/Go_lev.2_RestAPI/Lec13$   , yup I have both go.mod and go.sum , I did go mod init in the beginning

Comment: here is one detail: in /go/src/github.com   I have another folder that I had before during the lessons /go/src/github.com/RaminCH/go2_REST_API/lec13 (master)$ and here the main.go runs

Comment: It seems like the folder RaminCH has master privileges but RaminCH_self don't, maybe you know how I can shift ?

Comment: You can edit your question to provide information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sure go is installed in your system, you can try to add golang to your `$path` variables.

```
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/go/bin
```

And then you can try again.

Comment: # Go configs here

Comment: GOROOT=/usr/local/go

Comment: GOPATH=$HOME/go

Comment: PATH=$GOPATH/bin:$GOROOT/bin:$PATH

Comment: [ -f ~/.fzf.bash ] && source ~/.fzf.bash

Comment: should I add /bin to GOPATH=$HOME/go ?